# Positive Lookahead with javacsripts new RegExp() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following situation going on:

```
var x = "dot.test:semicolon;exclamation!Question?";
var separators = ['\\\!', '\\\.', '\\\(', '\\\)', ':', ';', '\\\?'];
var tokens = x.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));

//expected output : ['dot.', 'test:', 'semicolon;', and so on...]
```

This is working just fine. I would now like to transform the RegExp into a positive lookahead expression, which keeps the delimiters in the String. I am not sure how I would do something like this with javascripts `new RegExp()` function. I would like to include [A-Z][a-z][0-9] and all other signs pretty much as I will be parsing a normal text and will want to keep the delimiter in each and every case.

I would really appreciate some advice!

Comment: Like `x.split(new RegExp("(?=[" + separators.join('') + "])"))`? Note that if the separators are single chars, and they are just like you have, you may use `var separators = ['!', '.', '(', ')', ':', ';', '?'];` since inside `[...]` they do not need escaping. What is the expected output?

Comment: Oh, amazing, yeah pretty much like that! Is it possible to include the delimiter always with the previous object? E.g.: Right now, doing this I get `'dot', '.test', ...` - but I would like to have `'dot.', 'test:', ...` (?)

Comment: Please add expected output to the question. It is clear a lookahead is not enough.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Ok, you removed `(hello)`, I was puzzled what the expected output would be with that string inside. Now, try `x.match(new RegExp("[^" + separators.join('') + "]+[" + separators.join('') + "]*", "g"))` if you only expect the separators to appear after a token.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it, things don't have to get overly complicated with a question like this. Thanks a lot for your answer, the solution works perfectly. If you post it as an answer, I'd happily pick that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to match any chars other than those defined in your array and then those chars if present. Use

```js
var x = "dot.test:semicolon;exclamation!Question?";
var separators = ['!', '.', '(', ')', ':', ';', '?'];
var tokens = x.match(new RegExp("[^" + separators.join('') + "]+[" + separators.join('') + "]*", "g"));
console.log(tokens);
```

Not that you will only need to escape `-,`, `\`, `]` and `^` if you want to expand the separators list.